# Get modified mesh displaced by displacementMap in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am trying to get back and export the mesh that is being displaced by a displacementMap.

The shader is transforming vertexes according to this line (from
three.js/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/displacementmap_vertex.glsl):

```
transformed += normalize( objectNormal ) * ( texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).x * displacementScale + displacementBias );
```

This is displacing a vertex according to the displacementMap, mixed with the uv coordinates for that vertex.

I am trying to create this mesh/geometry so that I can then later export it.

**I have created a "demo" of the problem here: 
[Github Page](https://deadolus.github.io/threejs-stlexporter-test/)** 
I  would like the **displaced mesh**, as seen in the viewport, up on pressing exportSTL. However I am only getting the undisplaced plane.

I understand why this happens, the displacement only happens in the shader and is not really displacing the geometry of the plane directly.

I have not found a method provided by three.js and so  far have not found any way in getting the changes from the shader. 
So I am trying to do it with a function in the "demo.js".
However, I am a WebGL/three.js newbie and have problems re-creating what the shader does.

I have found exporters handling morphTargets, but these are of no help.
After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531109/three-js-vertices-does-not-update/24536525#24536525) I tried PlaneBufferGeometry, as this is closer to the shader - but this produces the same results for me.
I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941637/how-do-i-export-obj-from-three-js-geometry-that-is-being-displaced-by-glsl-shade) originally tried to produce something similar, but accepted an unrelated question.

In the end I would like to draw on a HTML-canvas which then updates the texture in real time (I have this part working). The user can then export the mesh for 3d printing.

Is there a way three.js can give me the modified geometry of the shader?
Or can someone help me translate the shader line in to a "conventional" Three.js function?
Maybe this is totally the wrong approach to get a displaced mesh?

**Update - Example is working**

Thanks to the example from DeeFisher I can now calculate the displacement in CPU, as originally suggested by imerso. 
If you click on the [Github Page](https://deadolus.github.io/threejs-stlexporter-test/) now, you will get a working example. 
At the moment I do not fully understand why I have to mirror the canvas to get the correct displacement in the end, but this is at worst a minor nuissance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that while still using a shader for the displacement, you will need to switch to WebGL2 and use Transform-Feedback (Google search: WebGL2 Transform-Feedback).

An alternative would be to read the texture back to CPU, and scan it while displacing the vertices using CPU only (Google search: WebGL readPixels).

Both alternatives will require some effort, so no code sample at this time. =)

Comment: Thank you for some pointers. I have started to look in to it, so far without success. 
I would like to do it in three.js, without switching to the underlying WebGL2. I am however trying to modify three.js GLSL code with your suggestions. If I manage to actually do it I hope to get it merged back at one point.

Comment: If you want to stay with WebGL1, there is no way to recover/save the GPU displaced vertices, so your only bet is reading back the displacement texture and displacing vertices in the CPU -- that is, you would not use GLSL for the displacement, but at least you would have the displaced vertices in CPU to export to disk. In WebGL2 you have transform-feedback, which is a way to read back the displaced vertices, so you could still use GLSL for that, then get the results using transform-feedback and finally export to disk.

Comment: Accepted as there seems to be no other way than what you suggested.
Three.js dev branch has WebGL2 renderer in development, but it seems to be not ready for prime-time yet. 
Looking at https://ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/gpu/bounce.htm seems to suggest TransformFeedbacks from WebGl2 would be a good way to solve the problem. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

[BABYLON.js](https://www.babylonjs.com/) can be used in conjunction with THREE.js and it allows you to displace the actual mesh vertices when applying displacement maps:

```
var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("Sphere", 64, 10, scene, true);
sphere.applyDisplacementMap(url, minHeight, maxHeight, onSuccess, uvOffset, uvScale)
```

See an example of the function in use [here](http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#P9UZG#9).

You can then use a for to loop transfer the BABYLON mesh data into a THREE mesh object.

Comment: I finally had time to test this.
It seems the Babylon.js (or at least your example) is doing it in CPU, as imerso suggested. 
However: the example code helped me to implement the same functionality for THREE.js! I updated the github code and it is now working, with the STLBinaryExporter I get the correctly displaced mesh. 
The "normal" STLExporter does somehow not export the mesh correctly. 
So I want to thank you for pointing me to a very good example how to calculate the displacement in CPU. I really appreciated it! Thank you very much for this!

Comment: awesome @Deadolus  !  Thanks very much.